# How to avoid glitches on superposed objects with openGL?

Tags: opengl

I would like, for example, to stack two cubes A and B.
The matter is that the top face of A is at the exact same position of B's bottom face.

This render some visual glitches as you can see :
[image]

Note that the pink grid can sometime be seen through any cube at some angle as well (not expected).

Is there any way to fix this without offsetting all my objects ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called *Depth Fighting* or *Z-Fighting* and is caused, that after projection the depth values are subjected to rounding and when depth testing happens the winner of the depth test depends on the rounding of the depth values of the participating fragments.

> Is there any way to fix this without offsetting all my objects ?

Yes, there are some techniques using the stencil buffer, with the caveat, that it works only for convex geometry. First you render your overlapping objects with depth testing and depth writes, but without color writes, setting a stencil mask. Next iteration you enable back face culling and draw with depth test disable, stencil test enabled (pass on the used stencil value) and color writes enabled. Within the region of the stencil mask things will overdraw according to the Painter's algorithm (i.e. the layers are in order as they're drawn).

Comment: Ok, this definitely helped, but I've got a free fly camera, and as soon as I move it to see the scene from another angle, it's a mess. I think it's due to the order in which I'm drawing the cubes. Do I have to change this order depending on where the camera is or did I miss something ?

Comment: @SQuat: There's no "one size fits it all" solution for your problem. But in general sorting objects far (from camera) to near is the canonical order to draw things in that case.

Comment: Okay, I think I'll stick with offseting then. It's a dev school project and I haven't much time to finish it. But I'll keep it in mind for next time, Thanks ;)

Comment: Well, I don't know what I have done, but after (manually) rollbacking to my previous code the glitch is gone and everything seems just right... I think I had something wrong with my vertex when I asked the question.